# unresolved import:monkeyrunner using monkeyrunner interpreter

Tags: python, eclipse, monkeyrunner

I am getting the error message using monkeyrunner interpreter, but the code runs absolutely fine. I have imported all correct PYTHONPATH and I am on mac machine and using eclipse Luna.

```
unresolved import:monkeyrunner
```

this is a very simple code, it shows RED for "waitForConnection"

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(30, "4df112090e855fdb")
print "connected!"
```

[image]

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `monkeyrunner` as the interpreter for that project in Eclipse.
Take a look at http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/03/eclipse-working-monkeyrunner.html for guidelines.

However, you should also check other entries in that [blog](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com) showing alternative approaches using 100% python solutions.

### EDIT

Try adding `monkeyrunner.jar` to the **Libraries** tab in Windows->Preferences->PyDev->Intenrpreter

Comment: thanks for that, I am using monkeyrunner interpreter, I followed the same steps as documented and there is just a RED error but it doesnt affect anything.

Comment: I have added "monkeyrunner.jar" under Jython interpreter, but I cannot added under Python interpreter as it only accepts Egg/Zip files.